# How to use Babel with fs.createReadStream

Tags: babeljs

I have an ES6 js file that I want to transpile down to ES5 using fs.createReadStream and babel.

```
fs.createReadStream('path.js').pipe(res);
```

It's just a for a quick and dirty prototype. I know not to serve pages like this in production.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out

```
const babel = require('babel-core');

...

    fs.readFile('src/pages' + req.url, 'utf8', (err, es6) => {
      const js = babel.transform(es6, {presets: ['es2015', 'stage-2']});
      res.write(js.code);
      res.end();
    });

...
```